# proto file doesn't compile because of extension field error

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

I have some proto files, which can be compiled under python and c++ switch. Now I'm using golang and the same command throws exception:

> protoc-gen-go: invalid FileDescriptorProto "xxx/yyy.proto": proto:
>   extension field "xxx.HumanReadable" may not have an explicitly set
>   JSON name: "humanReadable"
>   --go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Do you know what is the problem? is protobuf not compatible?

How can i ignore this field?

Comment: Please include the relevant `.proto` file `Message` definition - as well as the `proto` version (v2, v3?) etc.

Comment: sorry, my proto file was wrong. I have removed HumanReadable field and then it works.